# Pointers to static members of class

Tags: c++

From this reference:

> (8.3.3/3) A pointer to member shall not point to a static member of a
>   class (9.4), a member with reference type, or "*cv* void."

Why a pointer cannot point to a static member of a class?

```
struct S {
     static int f() { /*...*/ };

};

int main()
{
     int (S::*s)() = &S::f; // why?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why a pointer cannot point to a static member of a class?

Because for the purpose of membership it *isn’t* a member, merely for the purpose of scope. Apart from scope, static members are just like free functions, unattached to an instance of a class. You can use non-member function pointers:

```
int (*s)() = &S::f;
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way to say "for the purpose of membership it isn’t a member", besides, `static` members have access to protected and private members of objects of the class to which they belong so it's not just a scope relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you do `T::*`, you're saying "this thing requires an instance of `T` to use." That statement does not hold for `static` functions, which are callable without any instances of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use a regular function pointer, like so:

```
int (*s)()=&S::f;
```

Like GMan said, static methods don't work on instances, so they don't receive the hidden `this` pointer. This effectively makes them have a different signature from instance methods with the same arguments.